# Difference between GetModuleHandle and including header

Tags: c++, c, winapi

maybe stupid question, but i dont know answer. What is difference between using GetModuleHandle or LoadLibrary to load dll(and then to use function of that dll) and to include directly desired header. For example, with using GetModuleHandle:

```
typedef void (WINAPI *PGNSI)(LPSYSTEM_INFO);

// Call GetNativeSystemInfo if supported or GetSystemInfo otherwise.

PGNSI pGNSI;
SYSTEM_INFO si;

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(SYSTEM_INFO));

pGNSI = (PGNSI) GetProcAddress(
  GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32.dll")), 
  "GetNativeSystemInfo");
if(NULL != pGNSI)
  pGNSI(&si);  //calling function through pointer
else GetSystemInfo(&si);
```

But I can include windows.h header to directly call that function from my code:

```
#include <windows.h>

SYSTEM_INFO si;
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(SYSTEM_INFO));
GetNativeSystemInfo(&si);
```

The same applies for example to opengl32.dll, i dont know if it is better to include header file for opengl functions in my project or to use Getmodulehandle and GetProcAdress to invoke desired functions. What is the difference? Is first method with using getmodulehandle benefit in some way? Thanks for answers.

Comment: GetNativeSystemInfo() is special, it isn't available in earlier versions of Windows.  You really should use GetProcAddress for it.  This does not apply to opengl.

Comment: GetNativeSystemInfo() was just an example, but as i see now, it was good example, now i understand it well, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, make sure you understand that [GetModuleHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683199.aspx) and [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175.aspx) are not exactly equivalent. But since that's not directly part of your question, I'll leave off a big explanation and just suggest you make sure to understand the documentation in those two links.

---

To use a dll function directly as if it were like any other function, you don't just include the header. In addition to the header, somewhere in your project it is being told to link against a corresponding lib file. In your example, it would be kernel32.lib. This might be done through various means, such as linker settings in the project or having a `#pragma comment (lib, ...)` in a file.

When a program is built like that, code is written by the compiler to load that dll when the program starts. If the dll in question cannot be found when you actually try to run the program, then it will fail with an error message. You have no way to write code to catch the failure and take some alternative action.

For dlls that are part of the operating system (like kernel32.dll) or at least typically supplied with it, this immediate loading behavior isn't an issue since you can safely assume the dll will always be there. On the other hand, if you were to build against a dll which is not typically present, then you would have more of a concern. Either you would have to make sure such a dll is distributed with your program or else somehow try to make sure the user installs whatever other package is necessary to get that dll on their system.

Also, if the dll loads but any of the functions you're trying to use from that dll don't actually exist in it, then it will immediately fail with an error message. (It doesn't wait until your program tries to call the function. It finds this discrepancy when the program starts and aborts then.) This can be an issue if different versions of the dll exist out in the world.

Now, when you use LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress, you are asking for the dll to be loaded at the time of your choosing and asking to find a particular function provided by that dll. If either of those steps fails, you have the ability to write code to deal with it in some reasonable manner.

This can be used for various purposes. For instance, you could make a plugin mechanism where the program searches for and loads plugin dlls from some particular folder on the fly. Since the program doesn't know ahead of time which plugins will be present, LoadLibrary is the only way to do this.

Another thing LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress can be used for is to load a dll and call a function from it even when you don't have the proper header and lib files. If you know the name of the dll, the name of the function, and exact signature of the function (parameter types, return type, calling convention) then you have enough to write the code to load that dll and call the function successfully. Occasionally this can be useful. For instance, it's one way that people are able to use certain "undocumented" functions provided by Windows dlls.

Lastly, LoadLibrary/GetModuleHandle/GetProcAddress can be used to let you use functionality that doesn't necessarily exist on all the operating systems you want to support. This appears to be the reason for the code snippet you have that calls either [GetNativeSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724340.aspx) or [GetSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724381.aspx). The former is only available from WinXP/2003 on up while the latter is available on Win2000. If the code had just been written as a direct call to GetNativeSystemInfo, then the program would fail to run on Windows 2000. But instead, what you have there checks to see if GetNativeSystemInfo exists on the current operation system and only uses it if so, otherwise it falls back on the more widely supported GetSystemInfo.

So in the case of your example, which technique you choose to call that function depends on which operating systems you intend to support. If your software does not need to run on Windows 2000, then just directly calling GetNativeSystemInfo is a lot easier (and most likely the preferable way to go).

Answer (score 4):

Some functions don't exist in older versions of Windows and when you call a function directly, that function ends up in the import table of your program. If Windows fails to find one of the functions in the import table, the program will not run at all.

In your specific example, `GetNativeSystemInfo` was added in Windows XP and if you call it directly then your program will not run on Windows 2000 or older.

`LoadLibrary` is also useful if you want to support 3rd-party plug-ins etc.

Answer (score 1):

`GetModuleHandle` enables you to load dlls dynamically, what can be used for instance for implementing plug-ins or loading some resources on-demand.
Underneath, there is no difference between the two methods -- static library that you link just contains code that does dynamic linking when program starts (in C).

Comment: When i include header file and optionally with #pragma comment (lib,"opengl32.lib") i specify library it means that i am linking statically?

Comment: No, (lib,) is just to show the linker where to look for a library; indeed I don't think that linking dll as static lib is possible.

Comment: @san: There's a difference, no need to use GetProcAddress when you link to opengl32.lib.  Which is really what you want, using GPA on opengl would be quite painful.  And unnecessary.

Comment: @Hans Yup, but only on the implementation level.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, in this case I'd say its being used so that the dll/exe won't get loading errors from the windows LDR if the system(kernel32.dll etc) doesn't have exports that the binary **might** use, onr good example of this is the DEP functions for windows XP, which only exist in SP 2+, but its not a good idea to force a required SP, as it can cut down on the avaiable audience for the program. 
OpenGL uses the same sorta principle, due to the fact one can't predict the API support (and extensions), so one must check for it, then import it or an alternative with `wglGetProcAddress`

Another reason, which is more 'cheap' is so that one doesn't not have to link to certain libs and include certain headers, especially if your using say only 1 function from a very large SDK, this prevents other developers wasting time tring to get the huge SDK(they ofc will need the binary contianing the export)

Answer (score 0):

`LoadLibrary` and `GetModulehandle` both will work for the same stuff i.e; they will map the module on to the process at run time but in case of `LoadLibrary` it increases the reference count in the kernel perspective where as the later will not do so..